# JDK, javac not recognized

Tags: java, path, javac

I've recently installed java and have added it to my PATH Variables on my Windows 10 machine.

JDK in the System Path Variables
[image: JDK in the System Path Variables]

However I receive the error that javac is not present in the directory when trying to compile my program. This is probably a simple question but the other answers I have found are for people who don`t have the path at all.

Error of no javac

[image: Error of no javac]

I would appreciate any and all help you can provide.

Comment: you need to add that path to the `PATH` variable. A variable named `Java Development Kit` has no effect to your command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the path of your JDK to the `Path` variable not in the variable `Java Developement Kit`.

You can also reference other variables in your path variable:

```
|----------------------|-----------------------|
| Variable             | Value                 |
------------------------------------------------
| JAVA_HOME            | C:\Program...         |
------------------------------------------------
| Path                 | ...%JAVA_HOME%\bin;.. |
------------------------------------------------
```